# How do I remove non-English words from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, text-mining

I am trying to process a file with 2 columns of text and categories. From the text column, I need to remove non-English words. I am new to Python so would appreciate if there are any suggestions on how to do this. My file has 60,000 rows of instances.

And I can get to this point below but need help on how to move forward

Comment: What is a non-english word? Anything with special characters besides a-z?

Comment: not just special characters but words without any meaning like arghhhh or ohhhhh

Comment: If a row has one non-english word among many others, is it just that word to be deleted or the entire row?

Comment: only for that word to be removed. so if i have a sentence that says "arrrghhh this meal does not taste good at all" , to remove the word arrrrghhh and keep the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick.

```
import pandas
import requests
import string

# The following link contains a text file with the 20,000
# most frequent words in english, one in each line.
DICTIONARY_URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/' \
                 'google-10000-english/master/20k.txt'
PATH = r"C:\path\to\file.csv"
FILTER_COLUMN_NAME = 'username'
PRINTABLES_SET = set(string.printable)

def is_english_printable(word):
    return PRINTABLES_SET >= set(word)

def prepare_dictionary(url):
    return set(requests.get(url).text.splitlines())

DICTIONARY = prepare_dictionary(DICTIONARY_URL)
df = pandas.read_csv(PATH, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df = df[df[FILTER_COLUMN_NAME].map(is_english_printable) &
        df[FILTER_COLUMN_NAME].map(str.lower).isin(DICTIONARY)]
```

Comment: thanks for this. it seems to work but the filtercolumnname seem to not recognize my column text from this table. when I print(FIRST_COLUMN_NAME)  it is just showing text and when i write to file after running this code it is resulting in 1kb size so im not sure if it is reading the text

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove non English characters, such as punctuation, symbols or script of any other language, you can use `isalpha()` method of String module.

```
    words=[word.lower() for word in words if word.isalpha()]
```

To remove meaningless English words you can proceed with @Infinity suggestion but creating a dictionary with 20,000 words will not cover all the scenarios.

As this question is tagged text-mining, you can select a source similar to what corpus you are using, find all the words in the source and then proceed with @Infinity approach.

Comment: i am trying to remove non-English words only

Comment: @MugB - Then I think isalpha() would be enough. I forgot to mention earlier that is also removes emojis from reviews.